# DynamoDB scan performance issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, optimization, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am having problem with the performance of the DynamoDB and i want to clear something that i a little bit of confused.

- When doing `scan` for a 100 of records in the table `books` with condition using `Attr` (e.g. `Attr=('Author').eq('some-well-known-author-with-many-books-written')`). If the the `Author` has a 20 records found in the table does DynamoDB still scan the other 80 records?
- How does pagination works when doing scan?
- What is the consequences of consuming more than your allocated RCU and WCU?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions in order:

- Yes. `Scan` means an iteration over *all* records in a table. If `Author` is your partition-key and you need to find all books written by her, you should `Query` (not `Scan`), in which case it won't look at other `Author`s.
- Pagination works as expected: if you have `n` records in your table, and you `Scan` with limit set to `m`, DynamoDB will `Scan` `m` records while returning data for each page.
- DynamoDB will throttle your requests if you try to go beyond configured RCUs or WCUs. There'll be no cost impact, if that's what you are worried about.